# how to install vs code installation version and account settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a beginner with no knowledge of coding.
I have recently installed vs code I seem to have downloaded the wrong version I am not able to see the screen that has all the options. The app icon is blue whereas I see in videos it's blue and black. can anyone help?

Am I supposed to have an account after I start the App?

when I click on the account icon it says " turn on settings sync" what does this mean?

Comment: Stack Overflow's not a place that teaches people how to use an editor for the first time. Its for questions about code. When you author a question you need to include a minimal reproducible example, and debugging information. There is a website thats geared towards what you are looking for though, and another website where you can get support from people in a community.

Comment: "Discord is a good place" - **https://discord.gg/QdzwPRV**

Comment: "Reddit is also a good site" - **https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/**

Comment: _"For documentation about the subject you specifically asked for, you can visit this link."_ &nbsp; - &nbsp; **https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync** &nbsp; - &nbsp; _This site will introduce you to the VS Code feature called_ **`Settings Sync`**. _It syncs how you configure VS Code so when you make changes to VS Code you don't loose them  settings-sync._

Comment: Here is a link about setting up a **GitHub** account & **VS Code** acount, and using your **GitHub Account & User-ID** to log in & out of VS Code, sync your settings, and securly commit to your repositories. https://adamtheautomator.com/visual-studio-code-github-setup/

Comment: FYI, if you are new to writing any sort of code, this is a subject that has no boundary. The abstract world, is your to make what you will with it, but work, effort, self-learning, perseverance, and lots of coffee will be required for you to have a successful journey. (Like a lot of coffee. What you want to do is put an electric coffee-pot, and a can of Folgers next to your computer, trust me, you'll thank me later!)